# Is there any way to show post from permalink in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Normally we show single post using below method.
This is the route `<a href="{{ action('TestController@index',$post ->slug) }}">`
and `Route::get('/test/{slug}','TestController@index');`
This is the controller method

```
public function index(Blog $slug)
{
    return $slug;
}
```

But I don't need like that. I have generated permalink and save it into database in slug field. Now i want to show post from this permalink. See my table
[image]

How can i do t?

Comment: you don't want to show `https://127.0.0.1:8000` then show your controller , where yo have inserted data on this table

Comment: It's not a good idea to store full url, you MIGHT run into difficulties later on if there is a change in the domain. That said, if you really want to have permalinks, then why not use a separate table for permalinks that stores the slug where the link is pointed to?

Answer (score 1):

just put the slug column in href.

```
<a href="{{$post->slug}}">title of post</a>
```

I hope be useful